# Placing equation number on the left, tag on the right

Tags: equations, numbering, tag

I am using amsart class with default left equation numbering. I need to write an equation with number on the left and comment on the right as follows.

```
       qwer = asdf1    by Lemma A
(1)         = asdf2    since B = C
            = asdf3.
```

The command `\tag` changes numbering into comments, which is not what I want. Is there something like `\rtag` that makes comments on the right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand your question but this could work:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        qwer &= asdf1    &&\text{by Lemma A}\notag\\
        &=asdf2    &&\text{since } B = C\\
        &= asdf3.\notag
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image: pic]